# Nested insertChildren composite

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I've two nested composite

Composite A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:s="http://sig.com/faces"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <composite:insertChildren />
        <p:separator />
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

and composite B

(CASE #1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:s="http://sig.com/faces"
    xmlns:mycomposites="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomposites"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <mycomposites:a>
            <composite:insertChildren />
        </mycomposites:a>
    </composite:implementation>

</ui:composition>
```

Finally I have my view or page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:s="http://sig.com/faces"
    xmlns:gt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/template"
    xmlns:mycomposites="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomposites"
    template="/template/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">
        <mycomposites:b>
            <h:outputText value="test" />
        </mycomposites:b>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

"test" is not rendered.
For what I've seen this is because `insertChildren` in B is inside another composite `insertChildren` (A).

If I move `insertChildren` in B outside the composite works fine like so:

(CASE #2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:s="http://sig.com/faces"
    xmlns:mycomposites="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomposites"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <mycomposites:desktop>
            <!-- MOVED -->
        </mycomposites:desktop>
        <composite:insertChildren />
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

But CASE #2 doesn't do much for me. I need it like CASE #2

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem like you.

I have a component *A.xhtml*

```
<composite:implementation>
  <primefaces:datatable>
    <primefaces:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row.identityName}" />
    </primefaces:column>
    <composite:insertChildren />
  </primefaces:datatable>
</composite:implementation>
```

which is used in three files:

- common/approve.xhtml
- identity/technical/search.xhtml
- identity/business/search.xhtml

In the "identity/*/search.xhtml" pages i give many identitcal attributes and children to the component A.
Because this produces much duplicated code i tried to make s sub component of component A for the two identity pages.

*identity_A.xhtml*

```
<composite:implementation>
  <component:A identityAttribute="example">
    <primefaces:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row.identityName}" />
    </primefaces:column>
    <composite:insertChildren />
  </component:A>
</composite:implementation>
```

**I noticed, that the children, which i gave to identity_A.xhtml arent any longer displayed in the primefaces datatable.**

My Solution/Workaround for this Problem was to create a template for this two pages instead of a sub-component:

*identitySearch.xhtml*

```
...
<component:A identityAttribute="example">
  <primefaces:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{row.identityName}" />
  </primefaces:column>
  <ui:insert name="datatableChildren">
</component:A>
...
```

**Perhaps you can solve your Problem the way i did.
I hope, that there will be a solution, to use `composite:insertChildren`in nested composite components.**